# Mongoose populate function returning empty array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

There many questions about this, and i've looked at them all. However, my models and functions all match the suggestions or answers provided. I have a model with an array reference to another model, like so...

```
facilities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Facility' }]
```

and i push into that array like so...

```
$push: {
  facilities: req.body.facilityId
}
```

That all works. I can do a `findOne` without `populate` and i get a response with the newly pushed objectId.

```
{
    "_id": "5aa1771dc1558263eb80e790",
    "__v": 0,
    "updatedAt": "2018-03-14T16:04:02.000Z",
    "createdBy": "5a8b33d24456d4ad1bd97546",
    "updatedBy": "5aa1771ec1558263eb80e7a2",
    "createdAt": "2018-03-06T16:15:20.651Z",
    "deleted": false,
    "facilities": [
        "5a8b281ee3c022a8d0cf74a7"
    ],
    "identifier": "5437",
    "name": "District 1"
}
```

However, as soon as i try to use `populate` on that action, it returns an empty array.

```
Districts.find({}).populate('facilities').exec(function(err, districts) {
  if (err){
    res.json({error: err.message});
    return;
  }
  res.json(districts);
});

{
    "_id": "5aa1771dc1558263eb80e790",
    "__v": 0,
    "updatedAt": "2018-03-14T16:04:02.000Z",
    "createdBy": "5a8b33d24456d4ad1bd97546",
    "updatedBy": "5aa1771ec1558263eb80e7a2",
    "createdAt": "2018-03-06T16:15:20.651Z",
    "deleted": false,
    "facilities": [],
    "identifier": "5437",
    "name": "District 1"
}
```

I have also tried the suggested 'implicit specification' like this...(does not work)

```
.populate({path: 'facilities', model: 'Facility'})
```

What am i missing here? It seems some have hinted that it may be a problem with declaring the models from separate files.